# Creating an alias containing bash history expansion

Tags: bash, sudo, alias, bash-alias

I often forget to run a command with sudo, so I find myself often typing `sudo !!` immediately afterwards.

I tried aliasing this, but bash chokes on the `!!` part. Is there some way to represent this shortcut within an alias?

Comment: That's not a wild-card that's a history expansion feature. History expansion is performed before alias expansion so when the alias is expanded the `!!` are considered literal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AIUI the problem is that history substitutions (`!!`) are done before alias substitution.  I haven't tested this thoroughly, but it looks like `fc` can be used to get what you want:

```
alias sudothat='eval "sudo $(fc -ln -1)"'
```

Comment: No need for the `eval` (plus it may have some undesirable effects).

Comment: Without the `eval`, it won't parse things like the quoted strings correctly, and with double-quotes around the results of `fc` it should evaluate everything exactly once -- which is what you want.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: I've now tested this a bit more thoroughly, and it seems to work as expected (i.e. the same as typing `sudo !!`) for everything I've tried -- quoted arguments, pipelines, command substitutions, command substitutions containing command substitutions containing pipes...  I don't see any way to do this right without an eval.

Answer (score 7):

From a colleague at work:

```
alias sa='sudo `history -p \!\!`'
```

appears to do the trick

Comment: it should be noted that this only works when using single quotes (').

Comment: This won't handle quoted arguments properly -- for example, if you use it to rerun `echo "a   b"` (which prints `a   b`), it'll print `"a b"` (as in, the quotes are actually included in the arguments passed to `echo`, but the spaces between aren't).