# How to write a script to sudo the last command

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

Usually, for some commands such as `apt-get install xxx`, I forget to add `sudo` first, then I need to retype it. What I want is in such cases, I just type a simple command, for example `resudo`. It will sudo my last command `sudo apt-get install xxx`. Is it possible in bash?

Comment: [For `apt-*` in particular, there's `wajig`.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767/what-is-the-real-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude-how-about-wajig)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could just use bash's `!!`: it is a shortcut to rerun the last command.

```
sudo !!
```

Anyway bash offers many shortcuts for anything, you could just press the up arrow (in order to get back the last typed line), then press `^A` or `Home` and add `sudo` there.

[Here a useful bash cheatsheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/bash/)

Comment: Thanks, it works great. But still another question, it seems that !! is not recognized in bash script, why? for example, i want to get the last command last_command=$(!!), it doesn't work.

Comment: @Todd: `$()` evals a command, replaces it with the result of the command. You just need to do: `last_command=!!`, otherwise if `!!` was for example `echo Hello`, `last_command=$(!!)` will be expanded to `last_command=hello`.

Comment: @peoro: please test in your bash, last_command=$(!!) causes interpretation error. Seems !! is just not recognized.

Comment: @Todd: history expansion is (generally) disabled inside scripts because it doesn't make any sense.  Remember that scripts run in subshells, so if you could use `!!` in a script it'd expand to the previous line of that script, not the last thing the user running the script did.  If you're trying to make a shorthand for `sudo !!`, see [my answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/240180/creating-an-alias-containing-bash-history-expansion/240193#240193) for how to make a shell alias to do it.