# What does the command "sudo !!" mean?

Tags: command-line, unix, sudo

I saw the command

```
sudo !!
```

in a video.

What does this mean?

Comment: Run the previous command with sudo.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/247834/how-to-write-a-script-to-sudo-the-last-command).

Comment: @jmort253: SU, etc., is intended to be the font of all knowledge. Google is simply the search engine that leads here. We don't do RTFM except as a supplement to a usable answer.

Comment: Furthermore there is enough documentation on a linux distribution. Learn how to use commands like `info` and `man`. If you have them installed `man COMMAND` will give you information on what the command does like `man sudo`. If you don't have it installed install apt-file with `sudo apt-get install apt-file` then you can search with apt-file which packet contains the man command (if you are using debian or derivate of debian).

Comment: @jmort253: I'd love to see how you Google "!!".

Comment: @All - My apologies!  I thought the OP just had a typo and was asking what `sudo` meant. `sudo !!`, with the exclamation points, now that's an interesting question.  `sudo` without the exclamation points, just Google it as that's been answered dozens of times.  My confusion was based on not clearly reading the question!  +1 to the OP!

Comment: It means Sudo **with a vengeance**! If two machines are close by (2-3 inches), you can actually run commands on the *other* machine with this. It's that strong.

Comment: @The Pixel Developer: why don't you post your answer as an actual answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: @dag729 I didn't think it was worth it.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> **9.3.1 Event Designators**
>
> `!!` - Refer to the previous command. This is a synonym for ‘!-1’.

And from the [`sudo` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> **`sudo`** allows a permitted user to execute a *command* as the superuser or another user, as specified in the *sudoers* file.

So, `sudo !!` means to execute the previous command as the superuser.

Comment: Congratulations for the only response that actually answers the question.

Comment: So to emphasize this: !! is a history-function of the shell, and not in any way bound to sudo. You may use it everywhere where it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for telling, get the  "superuser" part?

Answer (score 10):

The double exclamation point "!!" is used to recall the last line entered into a shell. 
`sudo` is shorthand for "Super User DO" and is used when you want to execute a function with super user privileges.

So if I executed

```
./foobar
```

but then remembered I needed super user privelages, one could simply type

```
sudo !!
```

rather than typing`sudo ./foobar` all the way out. This is particularly useful when your last command was on the order of dozens of characters.

Comment: That's not accurate. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#References) (citing good references): _It originally stood for "superuser do" as the older versions of sudo were designed to run commands only as the superuser. However, the later versions added support for running commands not only as the superuser but also as other (restricted) users, and thus it is also commonly expanded as "substitute user do"._.