# How to easily execute last output line in bash?

Tags: bash

You probably encuntered the case where a package was not installed and the system was recommending you to install it using `apt-get install mypackage`.

I am looking for a quick keyboard shortcut for executing this last line. Obviously UP arrow would not bring it because it was not a command executed by you and only the last output line of the previous executed program.

Any ideas on how to get this behaviour in bash?

Comment: By default the output isn't "stored" anywhere. You might be able to hack together a solution… see here: [automatically capture output of last executed command into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955577/bash-automatically-capture-output-of-last-executed-command-into-a-variable)

Comment: what's wrong with `copy and paste`?

Comment: this is not an easy thing to accomplish.... http://www.falunk.com/?p=12

Comment: @MariusMatutiae that's what I did for years, but it requires me to switch from keys to pointing device select, copy, click, paste, clearly a "complex" process. Maybe I will endup implementing a shortcut my in the terminal (iTerm2).

Answer (score 3):

You can make an alias `xo` (name it whatever you like) that *reruns* the last command without printing any of its output, then runs the last line of that output as a command.

```bash
alias xo='$($(fc -ln -1) |& tail -1)'
```

Then after you attempt to run `myapp` and are told the command you can use to install `mypackage` which provides `myapp`, you can simply type `xo` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the command to install `mypackage` will run.

#### How This Works

`$(fc -ln -1)` behaves much like the history expansion `!!`. `!!` doesn't work in an alias or function definition, but `fc` (and command substitution with `$(` `)`) does.

`$(fc -ln -1) |& tail -1` reruns the last command, piping its standard output *and* standard error to `tail -1`, which discards everything but the last line.

Enclosing that in an outer command substitution causes the last line to be run as a command. Word splitting is performed on it (since the whole thing is *not* enclosed in `"` quotes), which is what you want.

#### Sources Cited

- [heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/users/216503/heemayl)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/621683/22949) to [How can I execute the last line of output in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621681/how-can-i-execute-the-last-line-of-output-in-bash) on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), which presents `$(!! |& tail -1)`, the core technique on which this aliasable method is based.
- [Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/240193/105707) to [Creating an alias containing bash history expansion](https://superuser.com/questions/240180/creating-an-alias-containing-bash-history-expansion), showing how `$(fc -ln -1)` simulates `!!` while working inside alias definitions.
- [My answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/621693/22949) to [the Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/621681/22949), where I originally presented this solution (with a somewhat different expository approach than I've used in *this* answer).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be `$(!! |& tail -1)`as it says in this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621681/how-can-i-execute-the-last-line-of-output-in-bash/621684

Comment: Your [now-deleted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/621684/22949) to [the related Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/621681/22949) looked potentially quite useful. Provided [the utility you recommended](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) really does have this particular feature, I suggest editing your answer for clarification and undeleting it. You needn't worry about the downvotes--once the post clearly shows that the method works and how to use it, they might be reversed--and even if not, it'll get at least *my* upvote, and probably others.

Comment: @EliahKagan : I can't tell you how many times I've banged the keyboard with <up><home><s><u><d><o>< ><enter>, assuming I don't return again after an annoyed typo. (It's worse on OSX) That utility has fewer keystrokes, reflects an appropriate sentiment and would get my vote.

Comment: @EliahKagan I've deleted my comment because I'm currently without any Ubuntu distribution to show how it works. I used to have that app in the past and it was working fine but I can't demonstrated right now how it works on Ubuntu that's why the answer was short and I couldn't copy/paste how it works. Feel free to try it and add the answer again. For instance, as you said it wasn't spam I don't event know the owner of the project... Thanks for your help